# Reading A File and Storing It In An Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, text-files

I am trying to read from a file and store the contents into an object called ToDoList(from what I assume is under the GetItem method). Then I am supposed to allow the user to add on to the list. But I am lost on how to create the object and print it.

```
public class ToDoList {

private ToDoItem[] items;

ToDoItem td = new ToDoItem();
String inputline;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = 0;

String[] stringArray = new String[100];



private void setItems(ToDoItem[] items) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("ToDoItems.txt");
    Scanner ReadFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (ReadFile.hasNext()) {
        String ListString = ReadFile.nextLine();
        stringArray[100] = (ListString);
    }
}

private ToDoItem[] getItems() {

    return items;
}

public void addItem(int id, String description) {
    stringArray[100] = (td.getId() + td.getDescription());

}

public String[] getAddItem() throws FileNotFoundException {

    try (PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new File("ToDoItems.txt"))) {
        do {
            System.out.println("add to the list? [y/n]");
            inputline = keyboard.nextLine();

            if ("y".equals(inputline)) {
                i++;
                stringArray[i] = (td.getId() + ". " + td.getDescription() + "\n");
                fout.print(stringArray[i]);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Here is the list so far:");

            }
        } while ("y".equals(inputline));
        return stringArray;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ToDoList{" + "items=" + getItems()
            + '}';
}
```

I am supposed to use the "getAddItem" method to allow the user to add to the list. But I can't figure out how to add an array to an object. let alone make the object.

Comment: Your question is far too broad - try to break it down and think about what you are trying to do. I suggest starting with thinking about what you want the setItems method to do and asking a new question just on that bit. That will allow you to provide more detail for example an example file and the expected contents of the array after the method has been executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little code to expand on what pininfarina said and to help you get going.

1. You need a ToDoItem class.  Something like this:

   ```
   public class ToDoItem {

       private String id;

       private String description;

       public ToDoItem(String id, String description) {
           this.id = id;
           this.description = description;
       }

       public String getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(String id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getDescription() {
           return description;
       }

       public void setDescription(String description) {
           this.description = description;
       }

   }
   ```

Then you need a ToDoList class to hold each item.  You backed yours with an Array, but I used an ArrayList:

```
public class ToDoList {

    private ArrayList<ToDoItem> items = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

    public ToDoList(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        try {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nextLine, ",");
                String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
                String description = tokenizer.nextToken();
                items.add(new ToDoItem(id, description));
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ToDoItem> newItems) {
        this.items.addAll(newItems);
    }

    public List<ToDoItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {
        items.add(item);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("ToDoList{");
        for (ToDoItem item : items) {
            builder.append(item.getId() + "," + item.getDescription() + "\n");
        }
        builder.append("}");

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This includes a constructor that reads the file and parses out items.  Each line in the file must be something like "1,something" because the tokenizer uses the comma.  Note that the Scanner actually destroys the file as it reads it.  You might consider using some sort of FileReader instead.

Finally you need a main class to run it.  Something like this:

```
public class RunIt {

    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ToDoList list = new ToDoList("ToDoItems.txt");

        try (PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new File("ToDoItems.txt"))) {
            String inputLine;
            do {
                System.out.println("add to the list? [y/n]");
                inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();

                if ("y".equals(inputLine)) {
                    System.out.println("enter a to-do using the format 'id,description'");
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(keyboard.nextLine(),
                            ",");
                    String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    String description = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    list.addItem(new ToDoItem(id, description));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Here is the list so far:");
                    System.out.println(list);
                }
            } while ("y".equals(inputLine));
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that there is a lot of room for improvement here (exception handling, more robust file reading, etc), but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been messing around with what you got. But One problem I have is that it keeps deleting the file. Which you did say it would. But every time I used scanner to read I don't recall it deleting. Could you explain that to me? Does it read it, then delete?

Comment: The problem isn't with the Scanner.  It's actually in the main() method.  The Javadoc on PrintWriter says this:  @param  file
The file to use as the destination of this writer.  If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.  The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

So it's actually the PrintWriter that is killing the file, not the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a broad question. Here's some design tips for you.

1. Create your collection class. This could be named ToDoList. Then create the attributes and behaviors of this class. One attribute will be the collection variable of your to do list items. You can use, List, ArrayList, etc. Behaviors could be add, remove, reorder, and etc.
2. Create your item class. Again with the attributes and behaviors. Attributes could include what to do, date, importance level, etc.
3. When you read your file, have your program to instantiate your ToDoItem class for every line, item etc. then save them into the previously created container class which is your ToDoList.
4. You can use your ToDoList class' addItem method (behavior) to have your users add more items into your ToDoList. If you want to keep the list even after your program closes. You can create a database to store your objects.

Good luck.